# What does "#include "myfile.php" do?

Tags: php, syntax

What's the meaning of the # symbol in the following line of php code:

`#include "myfile.php";`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments it out - this is a "Perl-style comment", with the same function as the "C-style comment" `//`. See [the documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php) for different ways of commenting in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

means that the line is commented out.

Answer (score 1):

`#` is a single line comment. It means that line of code is not being used.

Answer (score 1):

The hash is simply a single-line comment character.

Answer (score 1):

It marks the line as a comment, so the include directive isn't actually executed.

In the code below only myfile1.php will be included:

```
<?php
include "myfile1.php";
// include "myfile2.php";
# include "myfile3.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as a single line comment, exactly as // does.

In order to include a file, use

```
include("myfile.php"); # or
require("myfile.php"); # dies if fails to include
```